# How might I convert a .caf file to .wav using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, audio, wav

How might I convert a [.caf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format) file to .wav using C or C++?

Comment: Will [`afconvert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/afconvert.1.html) not work for you? Why do you want to write your own converter? And if you want to write your own, why are you asking how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OS X or iOS, then have a look at the AudioFile APIs in AudioToolbox.framework.